# Yolo accuracy, completeness, inconsistency

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo

I am at the point where I was able to use the Yolo tool to label all my images and store them in a folder. I need to figure out how to judge each image with the following criteria. Accuracy: Bounding box has to be tight as possible that contains the object. Completeness: Every object has a bounding box around it. Inconsistency: Each object has a unique classifier name. Duplicate of an object does not count. I am not sure how to proceed fully with judging the picture with these criteria. I am thinking I might need to create a simple script and grab the coordinates of each label in the picture and proceed somehow and someway. Any advice would be nice.

Comment: This question is very broad, it's difficult to provide help without specifics.

Comment: Well the hard way is you have to check manually the dataset 1 by 1. I don't really understand what do you mean by how to judge each image with following criteria? Basically when you train your dataset, it will give you the average loss and mAP based on your dataset. If the loss is high, then there's something wrong with your dataset.

Comment: Yeah, our group decided to go the hard way and manually check the dataset 1 by 1 and compute each criterion with a score.